# Alter output that relates to nested loops in Java

Tags: java, nested-loops

```
import static java.lang.System.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleFour{

 public static void createTriangle(int size, String let){
  String output = "";
  String x = let;
  int y = size;

  for (int z = size; z > 0; z--){
     int p = z;
     output += "\n";

     while (p > 0){
      output = output + " ";
      p--;
     }

     for (int d = size; d >= y; d--){
      output = output + x;
     }

     y--;
  }//End of for loop

  out.println(output);
 }
}
```

This code yields an output of the following when this statement `TriangleFour.createTriangle(3, "R");`  is executed in my program:

```
  R
 RR
RRR
```

I would like to modify my code to basically flip the output like this:

```
RRR
 RR
  R
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt. I slimmed down your code a bit, and renamed some variables to make it clearer.

```
public static void createTriangle(int size, String let){
        for(int i=size;i>0;i--){
            int fill = i;
            int space = size-i;
            while(space>0){
                System.out.print(" ");
                space--;
            }
            while(fill>0){
                System.out.print(let);
                fill--;
            }
            System.out.println();   
        }
    }
```

Pretty much the first for loop dictates how many rows there will be. If the `size` is 3, there will be 3 rows. The first while loop controls the amount of blank space per row. `space` is the number of blank spaces to print, and `fill` is the number of letters to print. You want `space` + `fill` = `size` every time the loop runs.

So in the first loop, `space` is 0. You don't print any spaces. `fill` is 3, so you print 3 letters, 0 + 3 = 3.

```
RRR
```

2nd loop, `space` is 1, print 1 space. `fill` is 2, print 2 letters, 1 + 2 = 3.

```
RRR
 RR
```

3rd loop, `space` is 2, print 2 spaces. `fill` is 1, print 1 letter. 2+1=3

```
RRR
 RR
  R
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: This helps much more than my powerpoint I have, thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: No problem. I'm no stranger to cryptic powerpoints, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are just trying to print it. try debugging before asking question  or write algorithm first before coding

```
public static void createTriangle(int size, String let) {
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            sb.append(let);
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: The class I'm taking doesn't allow StringBuilder, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify  condition for printing the space[" "] and character 
like below

```
  public static void createTriangle(int size, String let) {
    String output = "";
    String x = let;
    int y = size;
    for (int z = size; z > 0; z--) {
        int p = y-z;
        output = output + "\n";
        for(int j=0;j<=p;j++){
         output=output+" ";   
        }
        for (int d =z; d>0; d--) {
            output = output + x;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code (I have tested it):

```
public class TriangleFour {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createTriangle(3, "R");
    }

    public static void createTriangle(int size, String let) {
        String output = "";
        String x = let;
        int y = size;
        for (int z = 0; z < size; z++) {
            int p = z;
            output = output + "\n";
            while (p > 0) {
                output = output + " ";
                p--;
            }
            for (int d = 0; d < y; d++) {
                output = output + x;
            }
            y--;
        }
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
RRR
 RR
  R
```

Comment: @Hinklebart Thanks :-)